# Unable to close the Modal Dialog in Angular 2

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

This is my modal HTML where it basically renders a post in a modal and has a button to close the post(modal). Below are the two typescript files that are used to call the open method to display the dialog - 
home.post.component.html

```html
<div class="modal" style="width:780px; height: 500px; padding-bottom:20px;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="dialogRef.close()">Close</button>

  <div fxLayout="column">
    <div class="text-larger border-bottom-light-gray" style="padding-bottom:8px" [innerHTML]="post.title.rendered | keepHtml"><span style="font-size:0.500em;" class="pull-right">by Spoke Team</span></div>
  </div>
  <div fxLayout="row">
    <div fxFlex="75">
      <div class="margin-top-30" style="margin-right: 24px;">
        <div class="margin-top-10" style="overflow:auto; margin-bottom:20px">
          <div id="post-content" [innerHTML]="post.content.rendered | keepHtml"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="25" class="border-left-light-gray">
      <div class="margin-top-30" style="margin-left: 24px;">
        <div class="margin-top-10" style="overflow:auto; margin-bottom:20px">
          <div style="font-weight:600"> Related Posts </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

home.component.html - Parent View

```html
<div fxLayout="row" style="padding:0px; overflow: hidden;" class="bg-color-blue animated fadeIn" id="section1">
  <div fxFlex="70" fxFlex.xs="100" style="margin: auto;">
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.lt-lg="column"  style="margin-top:20px; padding-right:8px; padding-left:5px; padding-bottom:15px">
      <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="55" style="width:100%; padding-right:8px; padding-left:8px;" *ngFor="let post of cover.highlight">
          <div fxFlex="50" style="width:100%; margin-bottom: 0.5625rem;" *ngFor="let post of cover.highlight">
            <md-card style="padding:0px !important;" (click)="openPost(post.id)" class="cursor-pointer animated fadeIn wow" data-wow-offset="2.0s">
              <div class="stretchy-wrapper text-title" style="font-size:1.000em; color: white" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + post.featured_media_url + ')', 'background-position': 'center', 'background-size': '100vh', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'background-color': 'black'}"> 
                <div class="stretchy-wrapper bx overlay-post"> 
                  <div [innerHTML]="post.title.rendered | keepHtml" class="overlay-post-title"></div>
                </div>
              </div> 
            </md-card>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div fxLayout="column"fxFlex="45">
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.lt-sm="column">
          <div fxFlex="50" style="width:100%; padding-right:8px; padding-left:8px; margin-bottom: 0.5625rem;" *ngFor="let post of cover.rowOne">
            <md-card style="padding:0px !important;" (click)="openPost(post.id)" class="cursor-pointer animated fadeIn">
              <div class="stretchy-wrapper text-title" style="font-size:1.000em; color: white" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + post.featured_media_url + ')', 'background-position': 'center', 'background-size': '100vh', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'background-color': 'black'}"> 
                <div class="stretchy-wrapper bx overlay-post"> 
                  <div [innerHTML]="post.title.rendered | keepHtml" class="overlay-post-title"></div>
                </div>
              </div>       
            </md-card>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.lt-sm="column">
          <div fxFlex="50" style="width:100%; padding-right:8px; padding-left:8px;" *ngFor="let post of cover.rowTwo">
            <md-card style="padding:0px !important;" (click)="openPost(post.id)" class="cursor-pointer animated fadeIn">
              <div class="stretchy-wrapper text-title" style="font-size:1.000em; color: white" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + post.featured_media_url + ')', 'background-position': 'center', 'background-size': '100vh', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'background-color': 'black'}"> 
                <div class="stretchy-wrapper bx overlay-post"> 
                  <div [innerHTML]="post.title.rendered | keepHtml" class="overlay-post-title"></div>
                </div>
              </div> 
            </md-card>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div fxLayout="row" style="padding:0px; overflow: hidden; margin-top:40px;" id="section2" class="animated fadeInTop">
  <div fxFlex="70" fxFlex.xs="100" style="margin: auto;">
      <div *ngFor="let array of data; let i = index" fxLayout="column" class="animated fadeIn">
        <div *ngIf="i==2">
          <h1>SpokeOnline on YouTube</h1>
        <iframe  width="100%" height="600" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLGDMIYpr-Oq6L6dsHFxkHHs5-_AzBgSuX" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>

        <div style="margin-left: 40px" class="cat-title animated fadeIn" [id]="array.name">{{array.name}}</div>
        <div (mouseenter)='mouseEnter(array.name)' (mouseleave)='mouseLeave("")'  fxFlex="auto">
          <div fxLayout="row">
            <div style="width:100%; margin: auto;">
              <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutWrap="wrap" fxLayoutGap="auto" fxLayoutGap.xs="0">
                <div fxFlex="2" class="post-item-arrow"> 
                  <div *ngIf="leftArrow >0 && arrow===array.name" class="post-item-arrow-navigate cursor-pointer " (click)="loadPrevious()"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 36px">keyboard_arrow_left</i></div>
                </div>

                <div fxFlex="auto" fxFlex.gt-xs="50%" [fxFlex.gt-md]="30" *ngFor="let post of array.posts">

                  <md-card style="padding:0px !important; margin:15px;" (click)="openPost(post.id)" class="cursor-pointer animated fadeInRight wow" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                    <div class="stretchy-wrapper text-title" style="font-size:1.000em; color: white" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + post.featured_media_url + ')', 'background-position': 'center', 'background-size': '100vh', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'background-color': 'black'}"> 
                      <div class="stretchy-wrapper bx overlay-post"> 
                        <h3 [innerHTML]="post.title.rendered | keepHtml" class="overlay-post-title"></h3>
                      </div>
                    </div> 
                  </md-card>

                </div>
                <div fxFlex="2" class="post-item-arrow"> 
                  <div *ngIf="arrow ===array.name"   class="post-item-arrow-navigate cursor-pointer " (click)="loadMore()"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 36px">keyboard_arrow_right</i></div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div id="feed">
      <h1>SpokeOnline on Twitter</h1>
      <a class="twitter-timeline" data-height="600" href="https://twitter.com/SpokeOnline">Tweets by SpokeOnline</a> <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>



<!--<div  style="padding:0px; margin-top: 40px;" class="animated fadeIn wow" data-wow-offset="2.0s">-->
  <!--&lt;!&ndash;<div fxFlex="70" fxFlex.xs="100" style="margin: auto;">&ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--&lt;!&ndash;<div fxFlex="34" style="margin-right:30px;">&ndash;&gt;-->
      <!--&lt;!&ndash;<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/SpokeOnline">Tweets by SpokeOnline</a>&ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--&lt;!&ndash;</div>&ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--&lt;!&ndash;<div fxFlex="66">&ndash;&gt;-->
      <!--&lt;!&ndash;<iframe width="100%" height="600" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLGDMIYpr-Oq6L6dsHFxkHHs5-_AzBgSuX" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>&ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--&lt;!&ndash;</div>&ndash;&gt;-->
  <!--&lt;!&ndash;</div>&ndash;&gt;-->
  <!--<div>-->
    <!--<h1>SpokeOnline on Twitter</h1>-->
    <!--<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/SpokeOnline">Tweets by SpokeOnline</a>-->
  <!--</div>-->
<!--</div>-->
```

home.component.ts 
Here I am initializing and calling .open() on dialogRef. This is the parent view's typescript file.

```html
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, HostBinding, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialogRef, MdDialog, MdDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { HomeService } from './home.service'
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { fadeInOutAnimation } from '../_animations/index';
import { HomePostComponent } from './home.post.component'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  providers: [HomeService],
  animations: [fadeInOutAnimation]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public arrow ;
  public leftArrow = 0;
  @HostBinding('@fadeInOutAnimation') fadeInOutAnimation = true;
  category: any;
  // video: any = {id: 'wzrnuUOoFNM'};
  // baseUrl:string = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/';




  
  load: any = { per_page: 3, offset: 0, more: 3 };
  cover = { highlight: [], rowOne: [], rowTwo: [] }; // Array which contains last published pots in the json form. // ** We still have to make it display the posts most viewed instead of the last posts published **

  posts = { sports: [], entertainment: [] }; 
  post: any; // Variable related to when a single post is to be displayed  
  private mediaContentUrl = "http://spoketest.wordpress.com/wp-content/uploads/"; // Base link to fetch media content  
  buttonCount = { sports: 0, entertainment: 0 }; // to count next/back loading of next or previous posts in different categories

  constructor(private service: HomeService, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, public dialog: MdDialog) { 
        // this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.baseUrl + this.video.id);

  }

  getCover() {
      this.service.getCoverHighlight().subscribe(data => this.cover.highlight = data);
      this.service.getCoverRowOne().subscribe(data => this.cover.rowOne = data);
      this.service.getCoverRowTwo().subscribe(data => this.cover.rowTwo = data);
  }

  openPost(id) {
    this.service.getPostId(id);
    this.service.getPost().subscribe(data => this.post = data);
    this.openDialog(id);
  }

  openDialog(id) {
    let config = new MdDialogConfig();
    let dialogRef:MdDialogRef<HomePostComponent> = this.dialog.open(HomePostComponent, config);
    dialogRef.componentInstance.id = id;
  }

  getPostId(id) {
    this.service.getPostId(id);
  }

  getPost(){
    this.service.getPost().subscribe(data => this.post = data);
  }

  data: any[]; // empty array to store initial data from all categories
  getData(){
    this.service.getCategories(this.load.per_page).subscribe(data => { 
      this.data = data;
      this.category = this.data[1];
    });
  }

  // getBackgroundImage() {
  //   const backgroundImage = "./conestoga.jpg";
  //   const style = `background-image: url(${backgroundImage})`;
  //   return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(style);
  // }

  loadMore() {
    this.leftArrow = this.leftArrow + 1;
    console.log(this.leftArrow);
    // this.service.getData(this.category.id, this.category.offset, this.load.more).subscribe(data => {
    //   this.category.posts.push(data);
    //   this.category.offset += this.load.more;
    // });
  }

  loadPrevious() {
    this.leftArrow = this.leftArrow - 1;
    console.log(this.leftArrow);
    // this.service.getData(this.category.id, this.category.offset, this.load.more).subscribe(data => {
    //   this.category.posts.push(data);
    //   this.category.offset += this.load.more;
    // });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCover();
    this.getData();
  }
  mouseEnter(name) {
    this.arrow = name;
    console.log(this.arrow);
  }
  mouseLeave(name) {

    this.arrow = name;

    console.log(this.arrow);

  }

}
```

home.post.component.ts 
This is the modal typescript file

```html
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, NgModule, OnInit, Output, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialogRef, MdDialog, MdDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
import { HomeService } from './home.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';



@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'home-post-component',
  providers: [HomeService],
  templateUrl: 'home.post.component.html'
})
export class HomePostComponent implements OnInit {
  loading: boolean = true;
  post;
  id;

  constructor( private service: HomeService, public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<HomePostComponent> ) { }

  openPost(id) {
    this.id = this.service.getPostId(id);
    this.service.getPost().subscribe(resData => this.post = resData);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.openPost(this.id);
  }

}
```

Comment: would be a good idea to display the code that opens the dialog as well, especially the part where you are initializing and calling .open() on dialogRef

Comment: Hi ! I have added the part essential for the initializing and calling .open()